# HighSlide - Change width of an opened popup

Tags: highslide

How can I change the width (fixed dimension in px) of a currently opened popup?
Let's say from 400px to 600px.

Tried this, but doesn't work:

```
var expander=hs.getExpander(jq('#my_popup_id_HS')[0]);
hs.maxHeight=600;
expander.reflow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.height` instead of .`maxHeight`